# CSS transitions inline variables not being picked up

Tags: javascript, html, css

Inline variables aren't picked up by CSS transition, or they are being picked up however they aren't receiving the right information.

Below is an example of how the inline variables are set within the HTML

`<p class="hidden" style="--order: 1;" >ABC</p>`

How the variable is being called within the CSS.

```
section p {
    transition-delay: calc(200ms * var(--order));
}
```

Here is an example of the full HTML code with JS. The aim is to scroll down and the sections will transition in, and the paragraph will transition in after 200ms from each other.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;400;700&display=swap');
        body {
            background-color: #131316;
            color: #ffffff;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        }
        section {
            display: grid;
            place-items: center;
            align-content: center;
            min-height: 100vh;
            padding: 0px 20%;
        }
        .hidden {
            opacity: 0;
            filter: blur(5px);
            transform: translateX(-100%);
            transition: all 1s;
        }
        .show {
            opacity: 1;
            filter: blur(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
        }
        section p {
            transition-delay: calc(200ms * var(--order));
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="hidden">
        <p class="hidden" style="--order: 1;" >Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts.</p>

        <p class="hidden" style="--order: 2;" >Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia.</p>

        <p class="hidden" style="--order: 3;" >It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.</p>

        <p class="hidden" style="--order: 4;" >Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar.</p>

        <p class="hidden" style="--order: 5;" >The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="hidden">
        
        <p class="hidden" style="--order: 1;" >Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts.</p>
        <p class="hidden" style="--order: 2;" >The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
    </section>

    <script>
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
            entries.forEach(entry => {
                entry.target.classList.toggle('show', entry.isIntersecting);
            });
        });

        const hiddenElements = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden');
        hiddenElements.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually reading and taking it but `.hidden` class is overriding, what you can do it to toggle `hidden` class when `show` class is toggled, and make sure instead `transition-delay` use `transition` to add transition to the element:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;400;700&display=swap');
        body {
            background-color: #131316;
            color: #ffffff;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        }
        section {
            display: grid;
            place-items: center;
            align-content: center;
            min-height: 100vh;
            padding: 0px 20%;
        }
        .hidden {
            opacity: 0;
            filter: blur(5px);
            transform: translateX(-100%);
            transition: all 1s;
        }
        .show {
            opacity: 1;
            filter: blur(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
        }
        section p {
            transition: all calc(200ms * var(--order)); /* instead transition-delay */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="hidden">
        <p class="hidden" style="--order: 1;" >Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts.</p>

        <p class="hidden" style="--order: 2;" >Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia.</p>

        <p class="hidden" style="--order: 3;" >It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.</p>

        <p class="hidden" style="--order: 4;" >Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar.</p>

        <p class="hidden" style="--order: 5;" >The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="hidden">
        
        <p class="hidden" style="--order: 1;" >Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts.</p>
        <p class="hidden" style="--order: 2;" >The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
    </section>

    <script>
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
            entries.forEach(entry => {
                entry.target.classList.toggle('show', entry.isIntersecting);
              entry.target.classList.toggle('hidden', entry.isIntersecting);
               entry.target.classList.toggle('hidden', !entry.isIntersecting);
            });
        });

        const hiddenElements = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden');
        hiddenElements.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation and solution!